# Touchmove pinch zoom jumping position when scaling > 1

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to implement a pinch zoom on images.

The pinch zoom seems to be ok on first go - when scale ~ 1 - but when I scale the image to zoom in on a spot, let go and then try to zoom in on a new spot (and from an already scaled image) then the new touch seems to make the image jump.

The best way to see this is to run the sample code and to try to zoom in max on an eye, then let go, then try to zoom further in on the eye again.

```js
    var _img = document.querySelector('img');
    var _container = document.querySelector('#container');
    var _pinching = false;

    var _initialDistance=0, _initialScale=1, _initialTranslateX=0, _initialTranslateY=0, _translateX=0, _translateY=0;

    _container.addEventListener('touchstart', (event) => {
      console.log('touchstart '+event.touches.length);
      event.preventDefault();

      if (event.touches.length === 2) {
        const touch1 = event.touches[0];
        const touch2 = event.touches[1];
        _initialDistance = Math.hypot(touch2.clientX - touch1.clientX, touch2.clientY - touch1.clientY);
        _initialScale = parseFloat(_img.style.transform.match(/scale\(([^)]+)\)/)?.[1]) || 1;

        _initialTranslateX = _translateX * _initialScale;
        _initialTranslateY = _translateY * _initialScale;

        _initialCenterX = (touch1.clientX + touch2.clientX) / 2 / _initialScale;
        _initialCenterY = (touch1.clientY + touch2.clientY) / 2 / _initialScale;
        console.log('touchstart pinching '+_initialCenterX+' / '+_initialCenterY);
        _pinching = true;
      }
    });


    document.addEventListener('touchmove', (event) => {
      console.log('touchmove '+event.touches.length);
      if (_pinching && event.touches.length === 2) {
        const touch1 = event.touches[0];
        const touch2 = event.touches[1];
        const distance = Math.hypot(touch2.clientX - touch1.clientX, touch2.clientY - touch1.clientY);
        const scaleFactor = distance / _initialDistance;

        // Calculate the center point between the two touches
        const centerX = (touch1.clientX + touch2.clientX ) / 2 - _container.getBoundingClientRect().x;
        const centerY = (touch1.clientY + touch2.clientY ) / 2 - _container.getBoundingClientRect().y;

        // Apply transformations
        const deltaX = centerX - _initialCenterX;
        const deltaY = centerY - _initialCenterY;
        let translateX = _initialTranslateX + deltaX * scaleFactor;
        let translateY = _initialTranslateY + deltaY * scaleFactor;

        let scaleAmount = _initialScale * scaleFactor;

        console.log(`sa=${scaleAmount} / itx=${_initialTranslateX} / dx=${deltaX} / ity=${_initialTranslateY} / dy=${deltaY} / is=${_initialScale} / sf=${scaleFactor} / sa=${scaleAmount}`);
        if ( scaleAmount <= 1) {
          scaleAmount = 1;
          translateX = 0;
          translateY = 0;
        }

        const trans = parseInt(translateX) + 'px, ' + parseInt(translateY) + 'px';
        _img.style.transform = `translate(${trans}) scale(${scaleAmount})`;
      }
    });


    document.addEventListener('touchend', () => {
        console.log('touchend ');
        _pinching = false;
    });
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border:solid 1px grey;
}
img {
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 400px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.05s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.05s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.05s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.05s ease-out;
}
```

```html
    <div id='container'>
        <img src='https://i.pinimg.com/originals/f3/40/bf/f340bf0e86d65b5aaa709a0e98eae829.jpg'>
    </div>
```

How can I make this a smoother experience?